# The expression "se montrer + adjective"

Tags: expressions

> Elle a gobé mon histoire sans broncher. Alors qu'elle aurait dû **se montrer** plus vigilante.

I’m not certain how this expression differs in meaning from simply using "être":

> Alors qu'elle aurait dû **être** plus vigilante.

By the way, does the phrase "gober ~~~ sans broncher" mean "swallow ~~~ hook, line, and sinker"? The exact meaning of "sans broncher" eludes me.

Comment: [sans broncher](http://dictionnaire.reverso.net/francais-anglais/broncher), [gober](http://dictionnaire.reverso.net/francais-anglais/gober) 2.

Comment: You can compare *se montrer + adj* to "show onelself + adj"

Comment: @Laure: Actually, I've found out myself too that "sans broncher" means "without flinching", "without turning a hair", or "without batting an eye". The thing is that the meaning of these three English expressions leans towards "cold-heartedly without showing any emotion that is normally expected in the given situation" -- used in a context like "She killed the cat without batting an eye" etc. As such, they don't seem to fit well with the verbs "gober/avaler". I mean, "swallow a story cold-heartedly"? So I was wondering if I can use "swallow a story **without doubting a thing**" instead? Merci.

Comment: Then could say *sans la moindre hésitation* ou *sans hésiter*.

Comment: @Laure         Oh, I see. Do you ever use the phrase "gober ~~~ sans broncher" yourself? Merci.

Comment: **I** don't use the word *gober* in that sense but it's probably because I'm never in a situation to use it. Are you aware it's very familiar? But polite though.  *Gober sans broncher* is not a particular set phrase, but you can say it of course.

Comment: @Laure  Yes, I've noticed that the verb "gober" is tagged as "familier" in a dictionary. :)

Comment: Actually google returns lots of hits with "gober sans broncher" !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The meaning is indeed almost exactly the same, as you said.

If you want to enter the world of nuances in the other hand, there's arguably a slight difference in use, and it is that *se montrer vigilant* is focusing more on showing this characteristic at this moment and place specifically, not generally in life. In other words, *être vigilant* could more easily imply a judgment on the person, where *se montrer vigilant* is all about the situation, regardless of this person being cautious as a personal trait or not.

Comment: I'd say *paraître* is closer to the meaning.

Comment: @Archa closer to which meaning ? Yes, *se montrer + adj* **can** mean *paraitre*. But it's not the case in the specific use LUNA quoted. Who would ever advise someone to *seem* vigilant ? It would make absolutely no sense.

Answer (score 1):

> By the way, does the phrase "gober ~~~ sans broncher" mean "swallow ~~~ hook, line, and sinker"? The exact meaning of "sans broncher" eludes me.

*Gober* is used for animals who swallow a prey without chewing, especially for frogs eating flies. Figuratively, it means *to accept something without thinking*, generally by being too naive. It is quite common in French, with or without *sans broncher*.

> Je lui ai raconté n'importe quoi et il a tout gobé (sans broncher) ?

*Sans broncher* means that someone surprisingly does not react to a situation where most people would. Note that it is surprising *for the person who uses "sans broncher"*. So if I say:

> Il s'est fait pourrir par le prof mais il n'a pas bronché.
>
> *(He's been roasted by the teacher but he stayed surprisingly calm.)*

it means that I was surprised that he could stay so calm in that situation.

So *gober... sans broncher* means that someone naively believed a bunch of lies and that the person speaking is surprised it was that easy.